# Parsing data asynchronously using URLSession and SwiftyJSON not working

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to parse data using SwiftyJSON but for some reason I keep getting runtime errors. I left the errors in the code with //, there are 2 of them.  This is a sample of the data I'm trying to parse:

```
result = {
    cost =     {
        "airbnb_median" =         {
            CHF = 86;
            USD = 86;
        }
}
```

This is the function I use to parse the JSON after it has been retrieved by URLSession:

```
func parseJSONFromData(_ jsonData: Data?) -> JSON?

  {
    if let data = jsonData {

  do {
    let jsonDictionary = try JSON(data)
    return jsonDictionary

  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}

return nil
```

}

This is my custom JSON object:

```
class JSONObject {
  var airbnbUS: Int
  var airbnbLocal: Int

init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int)

 init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
  airbnbUS = (resultsDictionary["cost"]["airbnb_median"]["USD"] as? Int)!///Error Type 'Any?' has no subscript members
 airbnbLocal = (resultsDictionary["cost"]["airbnb_median"]["CHF"] as? Int)!
}
```

This is how I update the dictionary for the JSOn object values:

```
 static func updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: String, completion:
    @escaping (JSONObject?) -> Void) {

let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

_ = nm.getJSONData(urlExtension: urlExtension) {data in

  guard let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONFromData(data),
   let resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] //Error Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'
    else {
      completion(nil)
      return
  }

  for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {
    let jsonInfo = JSONObject(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

    completion(jsonInfo)

  }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to cast from Any to Dictionary `let costDict = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any]` and get another airbnb_median  dict from that

Comment: Please [search on an error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Error+Type+%27Any%3F%27+has+no+subscript+members) before posting.

Comment: I looked up by error first before posting, didn't find anything that I could use in this situation.